# Concept do-while-do-loop

Tags: c++, loops, while-loop

I often need something like a do-while-do loop. In the moment I implement this concept like this:

```
Instructions part 1 (for instance: read data)
while(Condition){
    Instructions part 2 (save data)
    Instructions part 1 (read next data)
}
```

I have to write part 1 twice, which is ugly. Is it possible to get rid of the duplicate? 
I think of a concept like this:

```
do{
    Instructions part 1
} while (Condition) do {
    Instructions part 2 
}
```

Comment: just a single `for` loop, see my answer

Comment: This is sometimes known as a "loop and a half".

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I prefer an approach with just one read/fetch

something like:

```
bool readData(SomeObject & outPut) {
  perform read
  return check-condition
}

while (!readData (outObj)) {
  // work on outObj
}
```

Comment: `while ( !readData( outObj ) )`.  Comparing a `bool` with `true` or `false` is senseless.  (And the type is spelled `bool`, not `boolean`.)

Comment: you're right, sorry too much java lately, but sice it was in pseudo code I think I didn't thought about syntax here, just on the idea.

Answer (score 5):

I usually solve similar problems by doing:

```
while (true) {
  Instructions part 1
  if (!Condition) {
    break;
  }
  Instructions part 2
}
```

Comment: or `for (;;)` for those who dislike while (true)

Comment: Perhaps, but it's not really a good solution, at least with regards to readability.  BigMike's solution was far better.

Comment: @JamesKanze agreed I like his solution

Comment: @JamesKanze One big advantage of this pattern is that the objects resulting from Part 1 have the correct lifetime. Hoisting them out requires them to be mutable and default-constructible only for the sake of avoiding a `break`, which is a net loss in my book.

Answer (score 1):

If you put `part 1` in a function that returns `bool`, you can do something like:

```
while (DoPart1())
{
    DoPart2();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You could define a little template function

```
template<typename Part1, typename Condition, typename Part2>
void do_while_do(Part1 part1, Condition condition, Part2 part2)
{
   part1();
   while(condition()) {
     part2();
     part1();
   }
}
```

and use it with functions, functors, or lambdas, i.e.

```
some_type tmp;
do_while_do([&]() { read(tmp); },
            [&]() { return cond(tmp); },
            [&]() { save(tmp); });
```

There is, of course, some overhead from the lambda capture, but at least there is no duplication of (possibly lengthy) code for `part1`. Of course, the template can be refined to take care of arguments to be carried (like `tmp` in the example).

Answer (score 0):

This can be done with a `for` loop.

```
for (bool flag = false; Condition; flag |= true)
{
    if (flag)
        DoPart2();
    DoPart1();
}
```